# почему не срабатывает обработчик ->el.addEventListener("click", part2);

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

```js
$("#liver").click(function() {
  $("#organs").hide();
  var childs = $("#part_1").children();
  for (var index = 0; index < childs.length; index++) {
    childs[index].style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  $("#part_1").siblings("#continue").css("visibility", "visible");
});

function part2() {
  var childs = $("#part_1").children();
  for (var index = 0; index < childs.length; index++) {
    childs[index].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  $("#part_2").children().css("visibility", "visible")
};

function part3() {
  var childs = $("#part_2").children();
  for (var index = 0; index < childs.length; index++) {
    childs[index].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  $("#part_3").children().css("visibility", "visible")
};

var el = getElementById('continue');
el.addEventListener("click", part2);
el.addEventListener("click", part3);
```

```css
.issues_for_liver>.child {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.issues_for_liver>#continue {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="organs">
  <button id="liver"> Печень </button>
</div>

<div id="issues">
  <div class="issues_for_liver">

    <div id="part_1" class="child">
      <input type="checkbox" class="liver_1">
      <label for="liver_1" class="liver_1">если у вас болит печень 1</label>
    </div>
    <div id="part_2" class="child">
      <input type="checkbox" class="liver_2">
      <label for="liver_2" class="liver_2">если у вас болит печень 2</label>
    </div>
    <div id="part_3" class="child">
      <input type="checkbox" class="liver_3">
      <label for="liver_3" class="liver_3">если у вас болит печень 3</label>
    </div>

    <button id="continue">Продолжить</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а почему ты думаешь, что он не срабатывает?

Comment: какой смысл использовать jquery для селекторов, и не использовать для событий? селекторы есть и в обычном javascript: https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем `JavaScript` коде немного модернизировал строку:

```
var el = getElementById('continue');
```

добавил осмысленное `document` к методу `getElementById`:

```
var el = document.getElementById('continue');
```

Для демонстрации того, что методы вызваны, добавил два `console.log`. Самое простое и удобное решение, для того, чтобы узнать, какой блок кода отработал и где.

Вот ваш код, внутри которого оба метода, соответственно и `addEventListener` срабатывают:

```js
$("#liver").click(function() {
  $("#organs").hide();
  var childs = $("#part_1").children();
  for (var index = 0; index < childs.length; index++) {
    childs[index].style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  $("#part_1").siblings("#continue").css("visibility", "visible");
});

function part2() {
  console.log('part2');
  var childs = $("#part_1").children();
  for (var index = 0; index < childs.length; index++) {
    childs[index].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  $("#part_2").children().css("visibility", "visible");

  var el = document.getElementById('continue');
  el.removeEventListener("click", part2);
  el.addEventListener("click", part3);
};

function part3() {
  console.log('part3');
  var childs = $("#part_2").children();
  for (var index = 0; index < childs.length; index++) {
    childs[index].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  $("#part_3").children().css("visibility", "visible")
};

var el = document.getElementById('continue');
el.addEventListener("click", part2);
```

```css
.issues_for_liver>.child {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.issues_for_liver>#continue {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="organs">
  <button id="liver"> Печень </button>
</div>

<div id="issues">
  <div class="issues_for_liver">

    <div id="part_1" class="child">
      <input type="checkbox" class="liver_1">
      <label for="liver_1" class="liver_1">если у вас болит печень 1</label>
    </div>
    <div id="part_2" class="child">
      <input type="checkbox" class="liver_2">
      <label for="liver_2" class="liver_2">если у вас болит печень 2</label>
    </div>
    <div id="part_3" class="child">
      <input type="checkbox" class="liver_3">
      <label for="liver_3" class="liver_3">если у вас болит печень 3</label>
    </div>

    <button id="continue">Продолжить</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Оба обработчика отрабатывают, причем в той последовательности, в которой они добавлены:

```
el.addEventListener("click", part2);
el.addEventListener("click", part3);
```

Что происходит в `part2`:

1. Скрываем все, что есть в блоке `part_1`;
2. Отображаем всех детей блока `part_2`.

Что происходит в `part3`:

1. Скрываем все, что есть в блоке `part_2`;
2. Отображаем всех детей блока `part_3`.

Что получается: жмем кнопку <kbd>Печень</kbd>, видим блок `part_1`, нажимаем кнопку продолжить, отрабатывают обе функции, по очереди и в результате мы видим блок `part_3`.

Comment: В данном случае el.addEventListener("click", part2); он срабатывает, но не отображается input и label.

Comment: @YR11, код работает. Полностью. Просто у вас нет понимания, как это работает. Расписал в ответе. Регистрировать на один обработчик несколько функций - можно, это не дублирующиеся слушатели, нет никакого игнорирования.

Comment: при нажатии на кнопку "Продолжить" должен исчезнуть : div id="part_1" class="child">и появиться: <div id="part_2" class="child">, а при повторном нажатии  должен исчезнуть : <div id="part_2" class="child">
      <input type="checkbox" class="liver_2">
      <label for="liver_2" class="liver_2">если у вас болит печень 2</label></div>  и появиться <div id="part_3" class="child">
      <input type="checkbox" class="liver_3">
      <label for="liver_3" class="liver_3">если у вас болит печень 3</label>
    </div>

Comment: а как сделать так,  чтоб part_3 появлялся только после повторного нажатия?

Comment: @YR11, посмотрите правку ответа. Добавил `removeEventListener` и перенес один `addEventListener`

Comment: cпасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы регистрируете несколько одинаковых слушателей события.

```
el.addEventListener("click", part2);
el.addEventListener("click", part3);
```

В таком случае дублирующиеся слушатели игнорируются.

Comment: а как быть в такой ситуации?